# Foreign Key Form For in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Error on the link_to. How can i access the reminders#destroy and reminders#update on the rake routes requiring a user_id and an id?

```
   Error
   <% link_to 'Update', user_reminder_path(s) %> 
   <% link_to 'Delete', user_reminder_path(s) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the method attribute from link_to and pass admin and reminder through its parameters

```
<% link_to 'Update', user_reminder_path(s, s.reminder), method: :patch %> 
<% link_to 'Delete', user_reminder_path(s, s.reminder), method: :delete %>
```

Comment: What`s being printed in your view on Reminder: s.reminder?

Comment: sorry i got confused i changed s.reminder to s.id. Thanks for the help

Comment: Don't worry. Is it working now? If so, mark it as answered

Comment: yes last question do you have an idea how to use the same form for creating and editing in ruby on rails

Comment: You can create a partial. Create a file like _form.html.erb and put your form inside it. Then, in your edit.html.erb and new.html.erb use <%= render 'form' %>